# HtmlUnit iframe with javascript src

Tags: javascript, parsing, iframe, screen-scraping, htmlunit

I am trying to scrape Google Keyword Tool and I run into the problem with iframes with javascript src. I thought that HtmlUnit will automaticaly handle this, but no. I was googling around and find some recomendation to use `page.asXml()` which should solve this problem, but it does not work for me.

Is there even any way how to accomplish such task, or is it impossible with HtmlUnit?

Here is example of such iframe:

```
<iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've not run into any problems with iframes.  Can you post your failing code that tries to test against a public site?

Answer (score 1):

The Google Keyword Tool uses a lot of AJAX, which might be the problem. I was able to interact with GWT via webkit.